# Which version control software compatible with remedy?

Tags: testing, version-control, compatibility, clearcase, remedy

Hi I am changing my versión control system and I investigated that perforce is compatible with bcm remedy. 
Does anyone knows other versión control system that is also compatible with bcm remedy ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BMC Remedy would be closer to [ClearQuest](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/clearquest/) than [ClearCase](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/products/us/en/clearcase/), but there is no [easy migration path](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014129032).

So if you can make it work with [Perforce](http://www.perforce.com/), stick with that choice.
[Serena dimesion](http://www.serena.com/index.php/en/products/featured-products/dimensions-cm/) is also a valid choice, as it is an ALM, Application Lifecycle Management (but I don't know the quality of the connector between BCM Remedy and Serena).

Comment: Thanks. I think serena dimensions also is compatible with bcm remedy ?

Comment: @JuanCarlos true, I have added it to the answer, but I don't have any experience of their compatibility in a migration scenario.